# Is this the right way to set up a kalman filter in dlm based on random walk?

Tags: kalman-filter, dlm

I have just started learning the filter for forecasting (please be gentle...), as well as the dlm package and its applications. I have the following code stolen from [link](https://github.com/RichJamo/Kalman-filter-testing/blob/main/Rankin%20KF_arima_using%20dlm.r) but instead of ARMA I used a RW model, which is then applied to an xts of data. My main question is how do I set up the RW model; particularly dw (evolution variances) - given that I have already used the variances of the daily differences as the dv (observation variances)? I used dv = var(dif) with dif being the daily differences , and dw = 0.1 below (as in the example in the [dlm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf) vignette), but am quite sure that I am misappropriating the package and/or the math.

```
#get data
y <- # any data in RW

# dif
dif <- ((y)[-1] - stats::lag(y, k = 1)[-1]) * 100 / stats::lag(y, k = 1)[-1] 

# we create the model in dlm
myMod = dlmModPoly(order = 1, dV = var_training, dW = 0.1, C0 = y[1]) 

# we put our data through a Kalman filter, using the model specified above
myFilter <- dlmFilter(y, myMod)

# we extract the filtered data
forecasts <- myFilter$f[-1]
```

Comment: Please write out the equations for your model so we can know exactly what model you're interested in. The above doesn't look like it does what you want based on your description. Also note that questions that are *only* about software are off-topic here.

Comment: I mostly want to set up an ARIMA(0,1,0) model that I could apply a Kalman Filter on but the dlm package doesn't seem to support this. The closest thing I have is either dlm(FF = 1, V = 0.8, GG = 1, W = 0.1, m0 = 0, C0 = 100), though I'm not sure how to set the W and V; or dlmModARMA, but once again I'm also not too sure on how to set the coefficients, since it doesn't seem to support modelling ARIMA, only ARMA. I'm also not too sure what dV is supposed to be.